# How to filter get_post with ACF by a checkbox field?

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, get-posts

So, I have a custom content type called "team" where I have an ACF field attached called "external" which is a checkbox. I am currently getting all the posts by passing the following arguments array to the get_post function.

```
 $args = array(
            'posts_per_page'   => -1,
            'offset'           => 0,
            'orderby' => 'menu_order', 
            'order' => 'ASC', 
            'post_type'        => 'team',
            'post_status'      => 'publish',

        );
```

What I'd like to do is run this in two functions checking if the field is or is not checked, essentially filtering by who is and isn't internal. I'm not sure how to set the meta-query up for this.

Comment: Check if $post and in_array.  More here - https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/checkbox/

Answer (score 0):

So, the scattered documentation on this is really less than clear.

For checking for unchecked posts added the following meta_query:

```
    'meta_query' => array(array(
    'key' =>  'external',
    'value'  => '0',
    'compare' =>  '='
    ))
```

For filtering by checked it was just this:

```
     meta_query => array(array(
    'key' =>  'external',
    'value'  => '0',
    'compare' =>  '='
    ))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using the `meta_query` parameter in the `WP_Query` arguments to filter posts based on the value of the ACF checkbox field.
Set to `0` for `unchecked` and Set to `1` for `checked` in value parameter in meta_query.

```
// Get internal team members
$args_internal = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => -1,
    'orderby'          => 'menu_order',
    'order'            => 'ASC',
    'post_type'        => 'team',
    'post_status'      => 'publish',
    'meta_query'       => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'external',   // ACF field key or name
            'value'   => 0,             // Set to 0 for unchecked
            'compare' => '=',
            'type'    => 'NUMERIC',     // Adjust the type based on your field type
        ),
    ),
);

$query_internal = new WP_Query( $args_internal );

// Get external team members
$args_external = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => -1,
    'orderby'          => 'menu_order',
    'order'            => 'ASC',
    'post_type'        => 'team',
    'post_status'      => 'publish',
    'meta_query'       => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'external',   // ACF field key or name
            'value'   => 1,             // Set to 1 for checked
            'compare' => '=',
            'type'    => 'NUMERIC',     // Adjust the type based on your field type
        ),
    ),
);

$query_external = new WP_Query( $args_external );
```